# Plotting multiple fit lines in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have a dataset in the form 
 [image]

I'm interested to plot a linear fit for each value in column Z, so that the o/p plot looks something like this:
[image]

I'm using the following code to create the linear fit for the whole dataset:

-----fit=polyfit(p1['X],p1['Y'], 1)

-----fit_fn = poly1d(fit)

-----x=plot(p1['X'],p1['Y'], 'r.',p1['X'], fit_fn(p1['X']), '--k',linewidth=2)

But while looping through Z col it breaks.

Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through groups of Z values properly (it's unclear how you're doing that in the code you showed) and you need to make sure all the plots end up on the same axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for _, group in p1.groupby('Z'):
    fit = polyfit(group['X'], group['Y'], 1)
    fit_fn = poly1d(fit)
    ax.plot(group['X'], group['Y'], 'r.',
            group['X'], fit_fn(group['X']), '--k',linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Dan. Also thanks for making me aware subplots can be so powerful.